# Dynamically updating color value of a div in angular

Tags: angularjs

I started learning angular a few days ago and I've been trying to update a div's colour based on a users text input but I can't seem to get it to work and I'm wondering if I'm going about it the wrong way or not.

I've seen many posts and answers on these topics where people want to update the color using checkboxes or something similar. For this there are a set amount of colors allowed so classes can be created and the ng-class directive can be used. Obviously I could do this with the text input box but I'm looking for functionality that allows for any possible hex colour value and I'd rather not write out every class for that.

My though was that this would work:

HTML

```
<div ng-app='root' ng-controller = 'index'>
  <input type ='text' ng-model ='myColour'>

  <div ng-style = "{'color': {{myColour}}}" >
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("root", []);

  app.controller("index", function() {

  });
})();
```

I don't really understand why this doesn't work so I'd appreciate if anyone would be able to explain why and possibly point me towards a better approach?

EDIT: For anyone who might also need a solution the problem was that in

```
<div ng-style = "{'color': {{myColour}}}" >
```

I had to get rid of the double curly braces but keep the single quotes around color like this

```
<div ng-style = "{'color': myColour}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Right hand side of your ng-style is an angular expression, so you don't need {{}} with "myColour" model. Change your code to

```
<div ng-style = "{color: myColour}" >
```

and that would work for you.

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything I've made a codepen http://codepen.io/MattJHodges/pen/wzWZWo

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle .  You are missing the final `}`

Comment: Where's that? I can't find it!

Comment: Your `codepen` was fine except you needed to add quotes around 'background-color'; try this out in it instead `<div ng-style="{ 'background-color': myColor }">`

Answer (score 0):

To update color using Ng style or simple style can also be used. you can use it as follows with style:{{colorVal}}. or with Ng style as ng-style:"{colorVal}"

Comment: That or an HTML5 input[type="color"] http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_color.asp. I prefer custom color-pickers like this one though: https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker. And don't forget the correction King Size made.

Comment: Neither of these seemed to do anything to help!